# Normalizing factor in Reciprocity of traces of Frobenius with solutions of equations mod p

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

One kind of Reciprocity tells us that we can count solutions to polynomial equations over finite fields and relate them to traces of Galois Representations with some normalization factor.

For instance: Solving the equation $Q(x)=x^2 +1 \mod p$ we consider the sequence $a_p = \#\{solutionsQ(x) \mod p\} -1$

Which can be recovered by taking the non-trivial character of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}[i]/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ evaluated at the Frobenius element at p.

Solving the two-variable polynomial equation of an Elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ mod p also gives us a sequence:

$a_p = p+1 - \#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$

which are recovered from the traces of Frobenius given by the representation of the Tate Module $T_pE$.

**Question:** 
Is there a conceptual framework to make sense of the $-1$ in Quadratic reciprocity and the $p+1$ in the Elliptic Curve case that allows us to in general relate these two phenomena? My intuition tells me it would be related to étale cohomology. Are these happy accidents? Traces of representations are, in general, not integers so I would expect some traces to not really make sense as a count of solutions.

Comment: The p+1 is easy to explain. The Etale cohomology of an elliptic curve is non-zero in three degrees: 0, 1, 2. 1 is the Tate module (or strictly speaking a twist of it) (so trace of geometric (rather than arithmetic) Frob_p is a_p), 0 is the trivial rep (trace of Frob_p is 1) and 2 is the inverse of the cyclotomic char (trace of geometric Frob_p is p). Now a fixed point formula says alternating sum of traces is number of fixed points and a fixed point of Frob is a point defined over the ground field.

Comment: And for the x^2+1 you have a 0-dimensional affine variety which geometrically is 2 points, so its H^0 is 2-dimensional and the associated Galois rep is 1+(character you write down). So that's the explanation in both cases and you're right, it's etale cohomology. In both cases the number of solutions is the trace of Frobenius on a virtual representation which you've guessed and which etale cohomology tells you.